# How to build a multi-module react-library where components can be imorted via import { MyComponent } from "shared-ui/my-component"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, rollupjs

I built a react component library using Vite.js. Here's the vite-config:

```js
// vite.config.js
export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    },
  },
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, "src/index.js"),
      name: "SharedUI",
      formats: ["es"],
      fileName: "shared-ui",
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      plugins: [peerDepsExternal()],
      output: {
        globals: {
          react: "React",
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Here's my folder structure:

```
shared-ui/
├─ src/
|  ├─ index.js
│  ├─ components/
│  │  ├─ index.js
│  │  ├─ select
|  |  | ├─index.js
|  |  | ├─select.component.jsx
│  │  ├─ input
|  |  | ├─index.js
|  |  | ├─input.component.jsx
├─ vite.config.js
├─ dist
```

The `shared-ui/src/index.js`-file contains the following:

```js
// shared-ui/src/index.js
export * from "./input";
export * from "./select";
```

The `vite build` command created one file `shared-ui.js`, which lands in `dist` folder.

If I install the package (in my case in an app using pnpm workspace) I can import the `Select`-component using:

```js
import { Select } from "shared-ui";
```

and it works.

But I want to achieve imports like:

```js
import { Select } from "shared-ui/select";
```

How is that possible? I tried using `rollup-plugin-includepaths` like

```js
// vite.config.js
import includePaths from "rollup-plugin-includepaths";

let includePathOptions = {
  include: {},
  paths: ["src/components"],
  external: [],
  extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
};

//... vite rollupOptions->plugins-option
plugins: [includePaths(includePathOptions), peerDepsExternal()]
//...
```

But the import fails.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you know it is easy:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    },
  },
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: {
        "single-select": resolve(
          __dirname,
          "src/components/single-select/index.js"
        ),
        input: resolve(
          __dirname,
          "src/components/input/index.js"
        ),
      },
      name: "SharedUI",
      formats: ["es"],
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      plugins: [peerDepsExternal()],
      output: {
        globals: {
          react: "React",
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

You also have to set the correct `exports` in the `package.json`.